# d3.js: how do I translate my graph when the user goes to the edge of the screen?

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, d3.js

What I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/DerNalia/GjmL7/4/

relevant code:

```
function mouseMove(){
  var x = 0; var y = 1;
   mouse = d3.mouse(this);
   console.log(mouse)
   // check if close to bounds
   if (mouse[x] < 10){
      console.log("shift left")
      circle.attr("cx", function (d,i) { return d.x - 5; } ) // translate x value
      text.attr("cx", function (d,i) { return d.x - 5; } ) // translate x value
      path.attr("cx", function (d,i) { return d.x - 5; } ) // translate x value
   }
   if (mouse[y] < 10){
    console.log("shift right")
      circle.attr("cy", function (d,i) { return d.x - 5; } ) // translate x value
      text.attr("cy", function (d,i) { return d.x - 5; } ) // translate x value
      path.attr("cy", function (d,i) { return d.x - 5; } ) // translate x value
   }
}
```

Currently, when you approach the edge of the screen, the circle nodes, the lines (paths) and text should all translate, but if you check out the fiddle, you'll see that they scroll in the wrong direction.

**The behavior I'm trying to accomplish:**
When the user scrolls to the edge of the screen, everything on the canvas should be translated away from the cursor -- the cursor is saying, "hey, I want to see what is over here"

but the problem is that (aside from not knowing how to translate everything on the svg) is, once the cursor stops moving, how do I continue to translate, until the cursor comes back on to the document? (of course, I'd set maxs and mins for the translating, as there is no point in translating past the data)

Comment: Do you want to just move the visible view area? If so the easiest and most performant way is probably to manipulate the 'currentTranslate' DOM property on the root svg element. Here's an example: http://www.svgopen.org/2002/papers/sorotokin__svg_secrets/Pan.svg

Comment: that method will work for now, I think, but ideally, I'd like to move the SVG by mouse position on the screen, rather than clicking and dragging, ya know?

Comment: I do need to adapt it to d3.js, though. I'll update my code in my fiddle when I get it ported successfully

Comment: I can't seem to port it over to d3.js. I'm really new to d3, so I don't exactly know what rules I have to abide by.